# Mysqli statement execute error : Result consisted of more than one row

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, stored-procedures

I am fetching the three values from TUsers using select query where I am getting the error as

Mysqli statement execute error : Result consisted of more than one row.

I have used DISTINCTROW for avoiding duplication and I am using Zend framework to call the procedure.

Here is the code:

Procedure:

```
         CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`` PROCEDURE `spfetchloginid`(in securityans   varchar(50),out email varchar(50),out loginidout varchar(50),out useridout varchar(50))
         BEGIN

         SELECT DISTINCTROW Email,login_id,user_id into email,loginidout,useridout  FROM DB.TUsers where SecurityAns=securityans ;

         END
```

Calling the Procedure in ZendFramework from Controller:

```
            $db=Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
        $spParams = array(1,'NewValue');
        $stmt = $db->query("CALL   spfetchloginid('$securityans',@email,@loginidout,@useridout)");

        print_r($stmt->fetchAll());
        $stmt->closeCursor();   

        $stmtresult10=$db->query("select @email");
        $email_to=$stmtresult10->fetch();
        $stmtresult10->closeCursor();
        $Emails=$email_to["@email"];
         echo $Emails;  

        $stmtresult11=$db->query("select @loginidout");
        $loginid=$stmtresult11->fetch();
        $stmtresult11->closeCursor();

        $loginids=$loginid["@loginidout"];
        echo $loginids; 

        $stmtresult12=$db->query("select @useridout");
        $userid=$stmtresult12->fetch();
        $stmtresult12->closeCursor();

        $userids=$userid["@useridout"]; 

        echo $userids;
```

Please tell me any good suggestions when using Zend and My Sql for calling the procedures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman//5.5/en/select.html):

> `DISTINCT` specifies removal of duplicate rows from the result set. [...] `DISTINCTROW` is a synonym for `DISTINCT`.

So saying this:

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW Email, login_id, user_id
...
where SecurityAns = securityans
```

just removes duplicates from the result set but if you have multiple rows with the same `SecurityAns` and they're all `securityans`, then your query will return multiple rows. If `SecurityAns` is an answer to a standard question like "what is your favorite color" or "what was your mother's maiden name" then you should be expecting a lot of duplicates so `SecurityAns` is certainly not sufficient to guarantee uniqueness.

You need to add more to the WHERE clause to guarantee unique results. Or, you could add LIMIT 1 but that's just a bandage over the real problem.

You're also probably running into a problem with your WHERE clause:

```
where SecurityAns = securityans
```

the should be true for every row in the table because I think the `securityans` column name will be used rather than the `securityans` parameter. Try using a different parameter name. For example, I see your duplicate problem with a procedure like this:

```
create procedure p(in id int, out result int)
begin
    select id into result from t where id = id;
end
```

but not with this version:

```
create procedure p(in find_id int, out result int)
begin
    select id into result from t where id = find_id;
end
```

Comment: Hello @mu the result which i am fetching is only one in spite  of that too the error it is showing the same

Comment: The table has only less row,the security question is one and it gives results only 1 row is there any method to avoid duplication.

Comment: @user1297878: I think you're also seeing a conflict between the `securityans` column name and the `securityans` parameter name and the column name is winning.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCTROW Email,login_id,user_id into email,loginidout,useridout  FROM TUsers where SecurityAns=securityans LIMIT 1 .I hope this is right it avoids duplication but when I am calling the procedures it is not getting perfectly.I hope you worked in Zend framework too

Comment: @user1297878: Zend has nothing to do with it, check my update. We're a couple seconds out of sync.

Comment: So there is some conflict in query where the column name is same and parameter is same ....Oh it is a good hint will change that and see and will give you the result

Comment: If the `securityans` is unique then you don't need LIMIT 1 or DISTINCTROW. But, you'll still have the parameter/column conflict; that's a pretty nasty bug and very difficult to spot.

Comment: Yes you are right the method and query is perfect and fetching the result in zend is also correct but can't get where is the error I have changed also the parameters name and even though  it is not showing any error it is quite a nasty bug

Comment: Mr mu there is some issue fetching the value with some unknown value like t1,11 in zend  is it any bug in database

Comment: for example SELECT DISTINCTROW  Email,login_id,user_id  FROM TUsers where SecurityAns='Sunny' LIMIT 1;

Comment: I am getting the result as in MY sql as                                Email:asa@ff.com login_id:User1 user_id:6 but when i am fetching in zend it is fetching the result as email:t1 login_id:1 user_id:1 it is bug or any problem with query tried all the methods can't guess why?

Comment: @user1297878: You have it all working now, right? I've been busy cooking dinner.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that all records have the same value in column 'SecurityAns' but different values for all other columns (usually each user has it's own email address, right?), no matter you use distinct or distinct row, your query will retrieve always more then one row.
So saying this, how do you want to assign multiple values to 'out' variables?
'In' and 'out' parameters in Mysql procedures are atomic variables that can only be given one and ONE ONLY value.
If you want to query a table for more than one row and do something with the retrieved data, I suggest you to do that using PHP and forget MySql stored procedures.